# How to iteratively interpolate elements of an array into a string in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string-interpolation

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
my_array = [1,2,3]
puts "Count numbers" + my_array.each {|n| " #{n}"}
```

What I would like to see is "Count numbers 1 2 3". But because .each returns the array, and not what is being returned in the block, it is not possible. How can I iterate through an array and interpolate each element one by one into a string? I'm not worried about formatting white space or new line characters at the moment. However, this is going to be used in the context of error logging, and I want to give my logger just one string to print, so I can't just print each element separately.

Comment: In general, `Enumerable#reduce` does the job of transforming enumerable into some aggregate. But in this particular case simple `my_array.join(" ")` would be enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect case for Ruby's `map` and `join` functions:

```
puts "Count numbers " + my_array.map{|n| n.to_s}.join(" ")
```

The `map` function maps each element in the array into its string representation, and the `join` joins them all together, separated by spaces.

EDIT: The `map` part can be left out in this specific case, where the elements are straightforwardly converted to strings. The `join` converts each element to a string anyway, so `my_array.join(" ")` is sufficient to solve this case.

Comment: The ```map``` part seems to be entirely unnecessary.  The join will convert each element to a string anyway.  You're iterating over the array a second time for no reason.

Comment: @MichaelB Yes, it is unnecessary in this specific case. However, StackOverflow is not just for answering present questions, but also provide help for future developers looking for answers, who may have a more complicated case than just "convert to string".
Anyway, thanks for the hint, I added a paragraph to that end.

Comment: This is actually what I'm looking for! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the situation, there may be no reason to pass a block at all.  For the example given, you could simply use the `join` method like so:

```
puts "Count numbers " + my_array.join(" ")
#=>  "Count numbers 1 2 3"
```

...or, interestingly enough, you can alternatively use the `*` operator to do nearly the same thing:

```
puts "Count numbers " + my_array*(" ")
#=>  "Count numbers 1 2 3"
```

NOTE:  I included the `*` operator option mostly just as a curious alternative.  I'm not sure it really has any benefit over the `join` method unless perhaps you're trying to make your code as cryptic as possible.  You never know though.  Its always nice to know what methods are available.

Comment: Or: `puts "Count numbers #{my_array.join(' ')}"`

Comment: _"the splat operator option"_ – that's not a splat operator but the binary `*` operator (aka "multiplication") which resolves to [`Array#*`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Array.html#2A-method).

Comment: @Stefan, I was really just using the term "splat" as an alias for the word "asterisk".  Maybe I shouldn't have.  If we really want to talk semantics though, I don't think using the terms splat or multiplication are correct.  This particular application is really an odd usage of the asterisk as an operator but in my mind has a lot more in common with "splat" behavior than it does with "multiplication".  Can you give a logical explanation as to how multiplying an array by a string resolves to converting array elements to strings and then joining said strings together with another string?

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you another answer based more specifically on your originally attempted solution:

```
my_array = [1,2,3]
my_string = "Count numbers"
my_array.each {|n| my_string << " #{n}"}

puts my_string
#=>  "Count numbers 1 2 3"
```

The main difference is that we're first creating a container for the desired output string and then concatenated to that string inside the `each` block.